# Visual Studio Crash

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I had a problem in the development of OLAP cubes in VS 2008 9.0.30729.
Reproduced of following way:
Create a new project Analyses Services type, add an empty OLAP cube, turn in the designer tab Calculations and BOOM! VS closes with an error.

Error text:

```
Version=1
EventType=CLR20r3
EventTime=130745897790726768
ReportType=1
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=c75196bd-eca6-11e4-99b6-005056a44f43
WOW64=1
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Signature problem 01
Sig[0].Value=devenv.exe
Sig[1].Name=Signature problem 02
Sig[1].Value=9.0.30729.1
Sig[2].Name=Signature problem 03
Sig[2].Value=488f2b50
Sig[3].Name=Signature problem 04
Sig[3].Value=Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design
Sig[4].Name=Signature problem 05
Sig[4].Value=10.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Signature problem 06
Sig[5].Value=4e7aeb0b
Sig[6].Name=Signature problem 07
Sig[6].Value=8c1
Sig[7].Name=Signature problem 08
Sig[7].Value=d
Sig[8].Name=Signature problem 09
Sig[8].Value=**System.IO.FileNotFoundException**
DynamicSig[1].Name=Версия ОС
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7601.2.1.0.18.10
DynamicSig[2].Name=Language code
DynamicSig[2].Value=1049
UI[2]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
UI[3]=Microsoft Visual Studio has encountered a problem and needs to close.
UI[4]=If you had files open that contained unsaved changes, these changes might be lost.
Sec[0].Key=LCID
Sec[0].Value=1033
ConsentKey=CLR20r3
AppName=Microsoft Visual Studio
AppPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

But I can not figure out what kind of file VS can not find.
Tell me, please, how to solve the problem?

Comment: Debug VS, reinstall VS, get later version... Really nothing more specific can be suggested.